# Getting intermittent failures of tests in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, karma-runner

#### Update 2:

After forgetting about this for a week (and being sick), I am still out of my depth here. The only news is that I reran the tests in Safari and Firefox, and now Safari always fails on these tests, and Firefox always times out. I assume I've changed something somewhere, but I have no idea where.

I'm also more and more certain there's a timing issue somewhere. Possibly simply code going async where it shouldn't, but more likely it's something being interrupted.

#### Update:

I'm less interested in finding the actual bug, and way more interested in why it's intermittent. If I can find out why that is, I can probably find the bug, or at least rewrite the code so it's avoided.

#### TL;DR:

I'm using Karma (with Webpack and Babel) to run tests in Chrome, and most of them are fine, but for some reason 7 tests get intermittent failures.

#### Details:

So! To work! 
The six first tests MOSTLY succeed when I run it in the debug tab, and MIGHT fail. The failure percentage seems higher when running it normally, though. These six tests are related, as they all fail after running a specific method which functions as a safe delete() for some Backbone models. Basically it's meant to check and clear() all linked models in the model to be deleted, and return false if it's not able to do that. 
And had the failures been 100%, I am sure I would find the error and wink it out, but the only thing I know is that it has to do with trying to access or change a model that has already been deleted, which seems like it's a timing thing...? Something being run asynchronously but shouldn't perhaps...? I have no idea how to fix it...

The seventh test is a little easier. It's using Jasmine-Jquery to check if a dom element (which starts out empty) gets another div inside after I change something. It's meant to test if Bootstrap's Alert-system is implemented correctly, but has been simplified heavily in order to try to find out why it fails. This test always fails if I run it as a gulp task, but always succeeds if I open the debug tab and rerun the test manually. So my hypothesis is that Chrome doesn't render the DOM correctly the first time, but fixes it if I rerun it in the debug tab...?

#### TMI:

When I say I open the debug tab and rerun the test manually, I am still inside the same 'gulp test' task, of course. I also use a 'gulp testonce', but the only change there is that it has singleRun enabled and the HTML reporter enabled. It shows the exact same pattern, though I can't check the debug page there, since the browser exits after the tests.

Output from one of the first 6 tests using the html reporter.

`Chrome 47.0.2526 (Mac OS X 10.11.2) model library:  sentences:  no longer has any elements after deleting the sentence and both elements FAILED
        Error: No such element
            at Controller._delete (/Users/tom/dev/Designer/test/model.spec.js:1344:16 <- webpack:///src/lib/controller.js:107:12)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tom/dev/Designer/test/model.spec.js:143:32 <- webpack:///test/model.spec.js:89:31)`

Output from test 7 using the html reporter.

`Website tests &raquo; Messaging system
  Expected ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1, context: HTMLNode, selector: '#messagefield' }) not to be empty.
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/Users/tom/dev/Designer/test/website.spec.js:163:39 &lt;- webpack:///test/website.spec.js:109:37)`

Now, the first thing you should know is that I have of course tried other browsers, but Safari has the exact same pattern as Chrome, and Firefox gives me the same errors, but the error messages end up taking 80MB of diskspace in my html reporter and SO MUCH TIME to finish, if it even finishes. Most of the time it just disconnects - which ends up being faster.
So I ended up just using Chrome to try to find this specific bug, which has haunted my dreams now for a week.

#### Source

Tests: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/117580/model.spec.js.html
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/117580/website.spec.js.html
Test output (Since the errors are intermittent, this is really just an example): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/117580/output.html

Comment: Showing the code of the tests too is probably a good idea :)

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to upload them, but I might just dump them on dropbox.

Comment: Hey, I recently had this problem. I had a missed service spy, that was working if another test ran first.

Answer (score 0):

OK, all tests now succeed. I THINK this was the answer: 
Some tests called controller, and some tests called window.controller. This included some reset() and remove() commands. 
After doing a rewrite, I still had failures, so I did another rewrite. As part of that rewrite, I decided to make all calls through window.*, and after that rewrite all tests succeeded.